# Moving from Flash to AIR, getting started?

Tags: flash, actionscript, air, distribution, flash-cs5

I've built an interactive disc for a camp for the last few years which was basically a custom video, audio, photo player and PDF viewer.

In the past, I've built it as a Windows Projector, but this year, I'd like to move to Adobe AIR. I was wondering about a few things in regards to AIR's capabilities and distribution.

1. Can AIR access the users filesystem? In other words:

   - Can I allow users to save images to their hard drive?
   - Can AIR load PDFs or load a local program, such as Adobe Reader?
   - Can AIR check for the existence of a particular program?
2. Does one AIR file run across all platforms? (Mac, Windows at least, Linux a plus)
3. Can I distribute an *offline* AIR runtime installer along with the CD?

We've traditionally distributed on a CD and I don't think this will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. There are some limitations, such as system security, but strictly speaking you can.
2. Yes: http://get.adobe.com/air/otherversions/
3. Yes, but you may need a license depending on some conditions: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime_distribution1.html

Comment: Please be more specific when answering number 1. I am curious to know about the subpoints I posted.